# Is it possible to authenticate from an Azure-hosted web app using an external AD?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, active-directory

We have active directory in place which runs internally (a server on our own company network).

We also have a web app hosted in Azure (entirely separate to our own network obviously), which all works - but we've now introduced functionality into it that means we need to authenticate.

Rather than roll out a separate membership implementation, is it possible the app in the cloud can offer login features which integrate with our own network's AD remotely?

What's involved in this?

Is it made easier if we move our AD to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely It will much easier if you move to Azure. **You can follow the Configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory sign-in** [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) which discuss about this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Hybrid Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/) and [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-azure-ad-connect)

Many organizations run into a similar scenario where they are already using an on-premises identity system (like Active Directory) and now want to utilize cloud based capabilities.

Hybrid identity can help especially when you have a mixture of on-premises and cloud based applications that are being accessed by same set of users (or identities)

There is a bit of setup involved with Azure AD Connect and multiple options available that you'll need to choose from depending on more specific requirements.

Amongst the different options, I have seen the Federation option work quite well in a few cases (doesn't mean you have to go with exactly this option, pick what works best as per your case).

In this case an organization that already had applications working with on-premises Active Directory, now takes Azure subscription(s) and Azure Active Directory tenant, which adds a verified domain that federates to the on-premises Active Directory (using Azure AD Connect and ADFS).

This way on-premises applications can continue to use Active Directory. At the same time newer cloud based applications trust Azure Active Directory tenant, which can federate the authentication process to on-prem infrastructure (after the right setup).

Once you have the right setup, Azure hosted web-app can trust Azure Active Directory which in turn works with on-premises AD.

You haven't mentioned which Azure service you're using to host the web app, a PaaS service like an Azure App Service or simply using Azure IaaS like a VM (or scaleset). You should be able to work with Azure Active Directory in all options AFAIK, but feel free to add more details in case you face issues.

[image]